# How to read and convert pdf files to image using in streamlit and pdf2image without saving the image locally?

Tags: python, streamlit

The code below accepts files of jpg, png and pdf format. When the file is in pdf format,
I want only the first page to be converted to an image and it should behave same as the image in else condition,

```
import pdf2image
import numpy as np
import streamlit as st
from PIL import Image

file= st.file_uploader("Choose file...", type=["jpg", "png", "pdf"])

if file is not None:
    if file.type == 'application/pdf':
        image = pdf2image.convert_from_bytes(file.read())[0]
    else:
        image = Image.open(file)

st.image(image, caption='Uploaded Image.', use_column_width=True)
```

Any help is appreciated.